# Docker run does not work anymore after upgrading cuda

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I was having problems trying to run COLMAP GUI inside a container because a  cudaErrorInsufficientDriver error.
So I used the Sotware updater to update the Nvidia driver.

However now I can not even run the containers anymore

```
docker run --gpus all -w /working -v /media/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/Work/colmap/WorkingDirectory/project:/working -it --rm colmap/colmap:latest

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"process_linux.go:432: running prestart hook 0 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'\\\\nnvidia-container-cli: requirement error: unsatisfied condition: cuda>=12.3, please update your driver to a newer version, or use an earlier cuda container\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.
```

What can I do now?
(Also I get very confused with the similar names for nvidia things like the nvidia driver, the nvidia toolkit etc. I think I have updated the driver so now this cuda>=12.3 refers to what?)